# On the zeros of functions

Tags: real-analysis, roots

Let $f$ have a second derivative on $\mathbb{R}$, satisfying $f (0) = a$, $f '(0) = 1-b$, $f' '(x) = - \sin x$.Let's ask if there is $b$ such that for any $a$, $f (x)$ has and only has $2019$ zeros (excluding multiple roots) on $\mathbb{R}$?I try to use Taylor expansion$$f(x)=f(0)+xf'(0)+\dfrac{f''(\xi)}{2}x^2.$$
So$$f(x)=a+(1-b)x-\dfrac{\sin\xi x^2}{2}.$$But next I don't know how to analyze it. Can you help me...

Comment: That means equation $(b-1)x-a=\sin x$,I want to use $\sin x=x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\dfrac{x^5}{5!}$...but I don't know it is right.

Comment: I should draw a diagram of $-\sin x$ and $a+(1-b)x$ to see what is going on.

Comment: @Mark Bennet well,Is there an analytical method? Thank you

Comment: You need to understand the function - there is only a possibility that the line cuts the sine  function while $a+(1-b)x$ lies between which values? What you are adjusting is the slope of the line. Perhaps start with an easy value of $a$. As $a$ changes, what would be the critical points? At the moment you haven't focussed the question. Polynomial approximations (Taylor expansion) won't do it (note eg that a polynomial of degree less than $2019$ can't have 2019 roots)

Comment: @Mark Bennet Thank you ,as you can see,I have already konw that Taylor expansion won't do it.but the question is that how to make $b$, I'm confused ...

Comment: I think that you made a small mistake. To me, $f(x)=a-b x+\sin(x)$.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici  Yes! I made a stupid mistake! Thank you,Do you have any solution to this problem?

Comment: @夜愿1998. I suppose that the derivative must cancel $2029\pm1$ times. This could give an idea about $b$.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici  But I still don't have any idea. It's hard for me to think about it for a long time...

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Sir,can you take a look at this problem, please https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3996264/how-to-calculate-the-following-integral-i-have-few-ideas