# How to calculate the following integral,I have few ideas

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, lebesgue-integral

calculate $$\int_{|\bf{R}^n}\dfrac{1}{\epsilon^n}\left(\dfrac{\exp\left\{\dfrac{1}{\left|\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right|^2-1}\right\}}{\displaystyle\int_{|\bf{R}^n}\exp\left\{\dfrac{1}{\left|\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right|^2-1}\right\}dx}\right)dx.$$
and $\exp\left\{\dfrac{1}{\left|\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right|^2-1}\right\}=0\left(|x|\geqslant\epsilon\right)$,I have no idea to calculate the intergral...

Comment: So do you have a few ideas, or no ideas at all?

Comment: @Smriti Sivakumar I'm sorry I don't have an idea

Comment: The integral in the denominator is just a constant which can be moved out of the outer integral...

Comment: @metamorphy Then how to calculate...Can you do it for me, please

Comment: @metamorphy I know what you mean, but it's different from the answer. The answer is 1...

Comment: Then you (or someone before you) have copied it incorrectly.

Comment: @metamorphy  I made sure again that I didn't copy it wrong. Is the answer to the book wrong?